Failed to connect to repository Command "/usr/bin/git ls-remote -h "https://github.com/project"
I am getting below error when trying to add my github private repository in to the jenkins configure system:
Error:
Failed to connect to repository : Command "/usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -- https://github.com/Project/django-todo-cicd HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/Analratna/django-todo-cicd/'
However i have done experiment using public repo, and it got added correctly.
I have connected my GITHUB account and Jenkins via creating a secret text in jenkins for GitHub. So, while creating a job I no need to add any creds, it should work by taking the secret text from Configure system.
I tried to add the git executable in Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Git -> Git Installations -> Path to Git executable but it didn't work for me. (For me Ubuntu machine on AWS it was under /usr/bin/git).
